# Reduce database touches for one to many data pull

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pdo, iteration

I have the following function which works properly and returns all of the rows from a specific table, then loops through each row to add data related to it as a subarray.

```
public function fetch_products() {
    $return = $this->db->all("SELECT * FROM consumables_products");
    
    foreach($return as &$r) {
        $r['consumables'] = $this->db->all("SELECT A.*, B.description FROM consumables_product_consumables as A, consumables_consumables as B WHERE product_id=? AND B.uid=A.consum_id", [$r['uid']]);
    }
    
    return $return;
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 1
            [description] => Test
            [consumables] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [uid] => 1
                            [consum_id] => 186
                            [product_id] => 1
                            [amount] => 5
                            [description] => 3 X 1" GREEN Direct Thermal
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [uid] => 2
                            [consum_id] => 185
                            [product_id] => 1
                            [amount] => 1
                            [description] => 3 X 1" ORANGE Direct Thermal
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This could get very inefficient with hundreds or thousands of rows in my `consumables_products` table, and an unknown number of rows in the `consumables_product_consumables` table.

I'm wondering if there is a way that I can do this in a single query, so that I don't have to do a separate call for every row in my `consumables_products` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single query could be used to get all results. This would require formatting the results differently...

The table `consumables_products` could be added as a (n INNER) JOIN.

```sql
JOIN consumables_products P on P.uid = A.product_id --or is it B. product_id instead of A.uid??
```

The implicit join on `consumables_consumables` could also be written in a similar fashion.

```
$results = $this->db->all("SELECT P.uid as productUid, P.description as productDesc, A.*, B.description 
    FROM consumables_product_consumables as A
    JOIN consumables_consumables as B ON B.uid = A.consum_id
    JOIN consumables_products P on P.uid = A.product_id
");
```

From there [`array_reduce()`](https://www.php.net/array_reduce) (or else a `foreach` loop) could be used to return the data in the specified format:

**Note** this is untested code...

```
return array_values(array_reduce(function($carry, $row) {
    $key = $row['productUid'];
    if (!isset($carry[$key])) {
        $carry[$key] = [
            'uid' => $row['productUid'],
            'description' => $row['productDesc'],
            'consumables' => []
        ];
    }  
    $carry[$key]['consumables'][] = array_diff_key($row, array_flip(['productUid', 'productDesc']));
    return $carry;
}, []));
```

That `array_flip(['productUid', 'productDesc'])` could be stored in a variable outside the loop though it would need to be brought in using a `use` statement or if PHP 7.4+ is used then an [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) could be used, which would allow use of that variable without the need for a `use` statement.

e.g.

```
$keysToUnset = array_flip(['productUid', 'productDesc']);
return array_values(array_reduce(function($carry, $row)  {
    ...
    $carry[$key]['consumables'][] = array_diff_key($row, $keysToUnset);
    return $carry;
}, []));
```

---

Also consider if all fields from `consumables_product_consumables` are needed. If not, select only the fields needed in order to minimized the returned data set.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. See, consumables_product_consumables can have 1+ rows associated with the UID from the first table. Your answer seems to only return one of these rows.

Comment: Oops I made a mistake with the JOIN condition for `consumables_products` - it should be either `P.uid = A.product_id` or `P.uid = B.product_id`, depending on where that product_id field is. Please see revised answer, which also has a shorter method for adding consumables to the list.